# How to browse for a specific cell and print data from another workbook in the cells below?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA code where I input a date in the following form : YYYY-MM.
I then want to find the cell that has this specific value in the excel sheet and copy data from another workbook in the same column.

For example, if I enter "2019-04", I want to find the cell with this value and fill the column under it using data from the files I have specific to this date.

I tried doing this with a for loop but haven't been able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
iter = 1
a = ActiveWorkbook.Name
YourValues & iter = Workbooks(b).Cells(xxxx) 'Whatever the second workbook reference is and use a do loop to add more 'iter' values
Workbooks(a).Activate
Cells.Find(What:="2019-04", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas,LookAt:=xlPark, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase = False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
n = 1 'or 2 or however far down below the value you want to place the new data
x = ActiveCell.Column
y = ActiveCell.Row
cells(y + n, x) = YourValues(tier)
```

Then perhaps n+1, iter+1 inside a loop.